Finding a function which is $L^1$ not $L^2$ and the integral is bounded by the square root.
So I have been trying to solve the following this past exam problem:

Find $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, not $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ with the property:
$$
\int_{A}|f(x)|dm\leq \sqrt{m(A)}\quad\text{ for all } A\in\mathcal{L} \text{ with } m(A)<\infty
$$

I tried to start solving the problem for a $A$ a bounded interval on $\mathbb{R}$ and then use some approximation theorem. The best function I found so far is
$$
f(x)=\frac{e^{-\sqrt{x}}}{2\sqrt{x}}
$$
Then we can see that $f\in L^1( \mathbb{R})$, not $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, because of $1/x$ problems, and for an interval $I=[a,b]$ with $0\leq a\leq b$:
$$
\int_{I}f\leq \int_I \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}=\sqrt{b}-\sqrt{a}\leq \sqrt{b-a}=\sqrt{m(I)}
$$
Now also we notice that $F=-e^{-\sqrt{x}}$ is an antiderivative for f. So if we have two disjoint intervals $I_1=[a,b]$ and $I_2=[c,d]$ then:
\begin{equation}
\int_{I_1\cup I_2}f=e^{-\sqrt{a}}-e^{-\sqrt{b}}+e^{-\sqrt{c}}-e^{-\sqrt{d}}\quad (1)
\end{equation}
So we would like to prove that
$$
e^{-\sqrt{a}}-e^{-\sqrt{b}}+e^{-\sqrt{c}}-e^{-\sqrt{d}}\leq \sqrt{b-a+d-c}=\sqrt{m(I_1\cup I_2)}
$$
I tested some values on desmos and it seems to hold but I can't get a direct proof, maybe the convexity of $e^{-\sqrt{x}}$ could give something. If this is solved then we could just approximate the measurable set by a finite number of disjoint intervals and get the result for f, then just do $g(x)=f(|x|)$ to get it for $\mathbb{R}$. In general if this doesn't work I believe that the idea of trying $g(x)/2\sqrt{x}$ should give an example for "very decaying" g.

This problem does not differ much from the analog on the compact interval $[0,1]$. The key is to observe why $f(x) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$ works for $L^1[0,1]$ (w.r.t. the same property): it utilizes the blow-up of the logarithm at the origin for $f\notin L^2$. To ensure $f\in L^1$ in the case of $[0,\infty)$ or $\Bbb R$, we can simply restrict the function to a bounded set.

We can simplify matters a bit. If the left side of the inequality is zero for some $A$, then the inequality holds trivially for such $A$. With this in mind, we can assume $f \equiv 0$ on $(-\infty, 0]$ and $A\cap (0,\infty) \ne \varnothing$. Replacing $A$ with $A\cap (0,\infty)$ if necessary, we can also assume $A\subset (0,\infty)$. We will construct a non-negative $f$, so $|f| = f$ holds. In addition, $f$ will be decreasing for $x > 0$, so we have
$$\int_A f(x)\, dx \le \int_0^{m(A)} f(x)\, dx,$$
for every $A\in \mathcal L$, $A\subset (0,\infty)$, with $m(A) < \infty$.
If we choose $f(x)$ such that $\int_0^{m(A)} f(x)\, dx \le \sqrt{m(A)}$ for all $A\in \mathcal L$ with $m(A) < \infty$, we shall be done. Indeed, if we do not worry about integrability matters for a minute, the derivative of $\sqrt{x}$ will suffice, i.e., $$f(x) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}},$$
for $x > 0$, and $f(x) = 0$ otherwise. We see that this $f\notin L^1$, but we can fix this by redefining the function to be zero after a point. Choose your favorite $N > 0$, and define $f(x) = 0$ for all $x\ge N$, i.e.,
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 \ & x\le 0\\\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}} & 0 < x < N\\
0 & x\ge N.
\end{cases}$$
Then, we have $$\int_A f(x)\, dx = \int_{A\cap (0,N)} f(x)\, dx \le \int_{0}^{m(A\cap (0,N))} \frac{1}{2\sqrt x}\, dx = \sqrt{m(A\cap (0,N))} \le \sqrt{m(A)}.$$
Lastly, it is clear that $f\in L^1(\Bbb R)$ but $f\notin L^2(\Bbb R)$, since $$\|f\|_1 = \int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(x)|\, dx = \int_0^N \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}\, dx = \sqrt{N} < \infty,$$
but $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(x)|^2\, dx = \frac14 \int_{0}^N \frac1x dx$$ does not converge.

I see this is more in line with the preceding questions of the exercise (this was the third part), but how to you prove the first inequality used, $\int_{A}f\leq \int_{0}^{m(A)}f$

It uses the fact that $f$ is decreasing and $A\subset (0, N)$ (or $A\subset (0, \infty)$). Do you see it now? @Bigalos

I tried for a bit and I see that the idea is that if $m(A)=a$ then A kind of has to contain (a.e) disjoint intervals of total length a. So it's like integrating the minimal set contained over the biggest possible values of f. It makes sense but I can't get a concrete argument, I tried to rewrite everything as characteristics or proving it for simple function and then MCT, but there has to be a quick proof. Any hints ?

@Bigalos Consider the map $\phi: [0,\infty) \to \Bbb R$ given by $\phi(x) = m(A \cap [0,x])$. Then, the image of $\phi$ is $[0, m(A)]$. Can you use change-of-variables now?

So as $\phi$ is Lipshitz then by Radermacher its almost everywhere differentiable and then we use change of variables ?

Oh wait, we can do the Radon-Nikodym change of variables, and it works if my calculations are correct
